# PHP script doesn't send email only downloads php file

Tags: php, email, button, submit

Hi Im trying to get a contact us page to get a email address and send it to an email. Everytime I click submit the php file just downloads. I have loaded php version file on the web server and its running php version 5.3.27 code below:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "nishantrama@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Sva Sva Spa Salon Coming Soon Notify Email";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if  !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
     if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


 // create email headers
 $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

Any everytime I click submit on my webpage it just downloads the file.

Comment: Suggests server misconfiguration. Is the file named something.php?

Comment: @ Phil the file is called contact.php

Comment: @ Phil when I try and load version.php it also downloads the file.

Comment: Are you sure php is enabled on your host? and if you are putting the file in the right folder?

Comment: @ Rafael PHP is enabled I just got en email from the web hosting company confirming it is. I am putting the contact.php in the web root folder. and the index.html files points to it. I will add my html to this comment: <form name="contactform" method="post"  action="contact.php">
      <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
        <input type="submit" class="go" value="Send">

Comment: Well *maybe* it is enabled, but if it's serving your PHP source files as a download then the server is either misconfigured, or PHP isn't actually enabled. This is an issue that is 100% to do with your host.

Comment: @ Rafael if the file wasnt pointing to the right place it wouldnt download at all. I have spoken to my hosting company and they assure me its not their servers and that PHP is installed and working

Comment: Hey All, When I ran it through a PHP code checker I got this:           PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in your code on line 19
if (!isset($_POST['email'])) ||